# Pattern is not matching in shell

Tags: shell

I am facing a small problem in shell. Actually one patten "CZ_VF_***_*_***BILL*___.*" is stored in the database to search the file on the server. 
I have one file located in server whose name is "CZ_VF_20121109_BILL_001.zip" but when I checked the file by using below command.

```
ls CZ_VF__________BILL____.*"
```

It is showing error (No such files or directory). Please help me on this.

Note : we can't change the pattern in the database.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_` is not a wildcard character, so ls can't find that file. You can replace underscores with question marks:

```
ls $( echo CZ_VF__________BILL____.* | sed 's/[_]/?/g' )
```